# How to solve "py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.flink.formats.csv.PythonCsvUtils.createCsvBulkWriterFactory"

Tags: python, csv, apache-flink

I'm trying to create a CSV file getting data from kafka by flink consumer. For example:

```
    def _read_from_kafka(self):
        bootstrap_server = self.config['source']['kafka']['host']
        bootstrap_port = self.config['source']['kafka']['port']
        kafka_topic = self.config['source']['kafka']['topic']

        deserialization_schema = self._get_serialization_schema()

        source = KafkaSource.builder() \
            .set_bootstrap_servers(f'{bootstrap_server}:{bootstrap_port}') \
            .set_topics(kafka_topic) \
            .set_starting_offsets(KafkaOffsetsInitializer.latest()) \
            .set_value_only_deserializer(deserialization_schema) \
            .build()

        return source

    def load_data_to_pg(self):
        env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()

        source = self._read_from_kafka()

        sink = FileSink.for_bulk_format(
            '/opt/examples/test.csv', CsvBulkWriters.for_schema(schema)
        ).build()

        env.from_source(source, WatermarkStrategy.no_watermarks(), "Kafka Source", type_info).sink_to(sink)
        env.execute("test_kafka->flink->CSV")
```

But getting next exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/examples/test.py", line 268, in <module>
    flink_consumer.build_csv_job()
  File "/opt/examples/test.py", line 207, in build_csv_job
    '/opt/examples/test.csv', CsvBulkWriters.for_schema(schema)
  File "/opt/flink/opt/python/pyflink.zip/pyflink/datastream/formats/csv.py", line 361, in for_schema
    if not delims:
  File "/opt/flink/opt/python/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
  File "/opt/flink/opt/python/pyflink.zip/pyflink/util/exceptions.py", line 146, in deco
  File "/opt/flink/opt/python/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.flink.formats.csv.PythonCsvUtils.createCsvBulkWriterFactory.
: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.flink.formats.csv.CsvFileFormatFactory.createCsvBulkWriterFactory(Lorg/apache/flink/shaded/jackson2/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/csv/CsvSchema;Lorg/apache/flink/tabl
e/types/logical/RowType;)Lorg/apache/flink/api/common/serialization/BulkWriter$Factory; from class org.apache.flink.formats.csv.PythonCsvUtils
        at org.apache.flink.formats.csv.PythonCsvUtils.createCsvBulkWriterFactory(PythonCsvUtils.java:68)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramAbortException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Python process exits with code: 1
        at org.apache.flink.client.python.PythonDriver.main(PythonDriver.java:140)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222)
        at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:98)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:843)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:240)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1087)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1165)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1165)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Python process exits with code: 1
        at org.apache.flink.client.python.PythonDriver.main(PythonDriver.java:130)
        ... 13 more
```

I've added next jars by .add_jars: flink-csv-1.16.2.jar and flink-sql-csv-1.16.2.jar. Tried to add them in dockerfile in ENV CLASSPATH, but nothing happens. Versions of jars and flink are the same.